# Unique products of array elements

Tags: matlab, cartesian-product

I have an array, for example `[3 5 7 11]`. I want to find out the unique multiples of these elements i.e.

1. product of pairwise elements -- 15, 21, 33, 35, 55, 77
2. product of three elements -- 105, 385, 231
3. product of four elements -- 1055.

I am currently confused as to how to go about it in an efficient way so that when I extend it to larger number of elements in the array, I don't explode my memory and kill my computer.

My current code:

```
prime_factor=[3 5 7 11]; 
for i=1:length(prime_factor) 
    pfm=unique([pfm cumprod(circshift(prime_factor,i,2))]) 
endfor
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Sure.. 

prime_factor=[3 5 7 11];

   for i=1:length(prime_factor)

     pfm=unique([pfm cumprod(circshift(prime_factor,i,2))])

   endfor

Comment: @RTn If you edit that into your original question, you can use proper code formatting and make it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic function is [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html), `nchoosek(v,k)` produces all combinations of `k` elements from the input vector `v`. Simply compute the product along rows of the output to get your desired result:

```
v = [3 5 7 11];
prod(nchoosek(v,2),2)
```

yields:

```
ans =
    15
    21
    33
    35
    55
    77
```

```
prod(nchoosek(V,3),2)
```

yields:

```
ans =
   105
   165
   231
   385
```

```
prod(nchoosek(V,4),2)
```

yields:

```
ans =
        1155
```